# Not able to create conda environment in macboook air(Resolvepackagenotfound)

Tags: python, anaconda

i have been trying to create an conda environment but i keep getting error saying resolve package not found however all the packages are already install.Even when i try to install any of the packages seperately it says package already installed.here is the error what i get

conda env create -f tfdl_env.yml

Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- win_unicode_console==0.5=py35_0
- tk==8.5.18=vc14_0
- qt==5.6.2=vc14_6
- vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
- libpng==1.6.30=vc14_1
- openssl==1.0.2l=vc14_0
- wincertstore==0.2=py35_0
- jpeg==9b=vc14_0
- six==1.10.0=py35_1
- zlib==1.2.11=vc14_0
- icu==57.1=vc14_0

Comment: can you show the content of your tfdl_env.yml file?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a similar problem, what I did to solve the problem was I removed all of those libraries which causing errors, by editing the .yml file. Why I did this? because some of packages are actually just support packages to others, which in my case the version of those packages didn't available any longer or didn't fit, but don't worry, once you update the .yml and re-run the command again, which in your case is "conda env create -f tfdl_env.yml", those failed package will be installed accordingly, triggered by the main packages that requiring those packages and find the most suited package.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But isn't the whole point of using something like conda the ability to recreate a defined environment on another machine?

Comment: Exactly, thus we create a new env for each project which has different packages version, but the point here was unable to install some packages due to its availability.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the mentioned packages by editing the .yml file and run the command for environment creation. It works fine. Hope this helps.